# How to auto-increment database id with uniqe product code and then reset it to 1 when change mont in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I am currently working with java spring boot. I am using JPA Repository and postgresql as database

My business owner want me to create id of transaction that contain

```
PRODUCT_CODE-YEAR-MONTH-INCREMENT_NUMBER
```

- increment number contain 8 length number

Example : 0000001, 0000011, 0000201

```
example : 48-2022-04-0000001
48-2022-04-0000001
48-2022-04-0000002
48-2022-04-0000003
-----> 48-2022-04-0000203
```

The increment number will be reset to be 0000001 when next month.

Will be:

```
48-2022-05-0000001
```

What the best way to do this?

Also if there is any query to select last data on given month and year?

Please help me, I just want to say thank you in advance

Comment: Please respect your readers enough to use proper case and punctuation in your writing. This site is meant to be more like Wikipedia, and less like a casual chat room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Multiple sequences, one per year-month

You don’t have one sequence. You have many sequences, one for  each month.

Use Postgres command [CREATE SEQUENCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) to create a sequence named for each month. I suggest using a sequence name that includes the year-month in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, YYYY-MM.

In Java, use the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) to represent a particular month.

You said:

> the increment number will be reset to be 0000001 when next month

No, don’t think in terms of resetting. For one thing, there may be exceptional circumstances where you need to create transactions for previous or future months. Resetting would preclude that.

So keep multiple sequences, one per month.